Jordan Measurability of $E_1 \times E_2$
I am trying to solve the following exercise in Introduction to Measure Theory by Terence Tao.
Let $d_1, d_2 \geq 1$ and let $E_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^{d_1}$,$E_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^{d_2}$ be Jordan measurable sets. Show that $E_1 \times E_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^{d_1 \times d_2}$ is Jordan measurable, and $m^{d_1 + d_2} (E_1 \times E_2) = m^{d_1}(E_1) \times  m^{d_2}(E_2) $
My attempt at tackling this as below:
As $E_1$ and $E_2$ are Jordan measurable;
$\forall \epsilon >0$, we have
$m(\overline{E}_1) - m(\underline{E}_1) < \epsilon $
and $m(\overline{E}_2) - m(\underline{E}_2) < \epsilon $
Therefore we have:
$\left[m\left(\overline{E}_1\right) - m\left(\underline{E}_1\right)\right]\left[m\left(\overline{E}_2\right) - m\left(\underline{E}_2\right)\right]<\epsilon^2$
Expanding this, we get:
$m(\overline{E}_1)m(\overline{E}_2) - m(\overline{E}_1)m(\underline{E}_2) - m(\underline{E}_1)m(\overline{E}_2) +m(\underline{E}_1)m(\underline{E}_2) < \epsilon^2$
and so:
$m(\overline{E}_1)m(\overline{E}_2)+m(\underline{E}_1)m(\underline{E}_2) < \epsilon^2$
which implies
$m(\overline{E}_1)m(\overline{E}_2)-m(\underline{E}_1)m(\underline{E}_2) < \epsilon^2$
and therefore:
$m(\overline{E}_1 \times \overline{E}_2)-m(\underline{E}_1 \times \underline{E}_2) < \epsilon^2$
So the cartesian product of two jordan measurable sets are jordan measurable.
Now we want to show that $m^{d_1 + d_2} (E_1 \times E_2) = m^{d_1}(E_1) \times  m^{d_2}(E_2) $:
We will show that $m^{d_1 \times d_2} (E_1 \times E_2) - m^{d_1}(E_1) m^{d_2}(E_2) < \epsilon$
Let $E_1 = \cup^N [x_i , x_{i+1}[ \times [y_j , y_{j+1}[$ and $E_2 = \cup^M [x_k , x_{k+1}[ \times [y_l , y_{l+1}[$
for $N,M \to \infty$
$m^{d_1 \times d_2} (E_1 \times E_2) - m^{d_1}(E_1) m^{d_2}(E_2) $
$
= m^{d_1\times d_2}(\cup^{N,M} [x_i , x_{i+1}[ \times [y_j , y_{j+1}[ \times [x_k , x_{k+1}[ \times [y_l , y_{l+1}[) - $
$
m^{d_1}(\cup^N [x_i , x_{i+1}[ \times [y_j , y_{j+1}[) m^{d_2} \cup^M[x_k , x_{k+1}[ \times [y_l , y_{l+1}[$
so by subadditivity:
$\sum^{N,M} m((x_{i+1} - x_i)(y_{j+1}-y_j) \times (x_{k+1} - x_k)(y_{l+1}-y_l) )  - m^{d_1}(\cup^N [x_i , x_{i+1}[ \times [y_j , y_{j+1}[) m^{d_2} \cup^M[x_k , x_{k+1}[ \times [y_l , y_{l+1}[$
$\sum^{N} m^{d_1}((x_{i+1} - x_i)(y_{j+1}-y_j) \sum^{M}  m^{d_2}(x_{k+1} - x_k)(y_{l+1}-y_l) )  - \sum^N m^{d_1}( (x_{i+1}-x_i) \times (y_{j+1}-y_j)) \sum^{M} m^{d_2} (x_{k+1}-x_k \times (y_{l+1}-y_l) \to 0$
QED
Does my proof make sense or do I have any mistakes or ambiguities that I should improve?

I'm not quite sure how $$\begin{aligned}m(\overline{E}_1)m(\overline{E}_2) - m(\overline{E}_1)m(\underline{E}_2) - m(\underline{E}_1)m(\overline{E}_2) +m(\underline{E}_1)m(\underline{E}_2) < \epsilon^2\\Rightarrow
m(\overline{E}_1)m(\overline{E}_2)+m(\underline{E}_1)m(\underline{E}_2) < \epsilon^2\end{aligned}$$

You're also dropped out a lot of parentheses, "$\times$". Not quite consistent.

As $E_1 , E_2$ are Jordan measurable, I decided to express $\overline{E}{1,2} = \underline{E}{1,2} + \eta$ where $\eta$ goes to 0, the above inequality became:
$$m(\overline{E}_1) m(\overline{E}_2) - m(\underline{E}_1 + \eta)m(\underline{E}_2) - m(\underline{E}_1)m(\underline{E}_2 + \eta) + m(\underline{E}_1) m(\underline{E}_2)  $$ So when I expand this, everything I multiplied by $\eta$ went to 0, so I ended up with $m(\overline{E}_1)m(\overline{E}_2) - m(\underline{E}_1) m(\underline{E}_2)$

What does $\overline E_{1,2}=\underline E_{1,2}+\eta$ even mean?

I was trying to say that as both $E_1$ and $E_2$ are jordan measurable, by definition, the difference between the measure of the outer cover and the measure of the inner cover will only differ by $\eta$ that goes to 0, so I could write the measure of the outer cover as the sum of the measure of the inner cover plus an infinitesimal
